# How do we connect AMPS[CRANK UP THE AMPS] Server and Apache Flink for Real time stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, connection, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are subscribing the real time data from AMPS[CRANK UP THE AMPS] Server as source of Apache flink. Any idea about about how to connect both of them like kafka.

Amps Server : http://www.crankuptheamps.com/amps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Apache Flink doesn't provide any out of the box connector for AMPS as you could see [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-connectors). But, it does provide an extensible Source/Sink interface that can be used to tap in any custom source/sink.

You can create your own AMPS source connector by extending `RichSourceFunction` and passing it to `addSource` method as mentioned in this [flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources). Refer the [Java Client API](http://www.crankuptheamps.com/documentation/client-apis/java/) provided by crankuptheamps for connecting to the source topic and subscribe for messages.

```
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.RichSourceFunction;
import com.crankuptheamps.client.Client;
import com.crankuptheamps.client.Message;

public class AMPSSource extends RichSourceFunction<String> {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8708182052610791593L;
    private String name, topic, connectionString;
    private Client client;

    public AMPSSource(String name, String connectionString, String topic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        // We create a Client, then connect() and logon()
        client = new Client(this.name);
        client.connect(this.connectionString);
        client.logon();
    }

    public void run(SourceContext<String> sourceContext) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Here, we iterate over messages in the MessageStream returned by
         * subscribe method
         */
        for (Message message : client.subscribe(this.topic)) {
            sourceContext.collect(message.getData());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        try {
            cancel();
        } finally {
            super.close();
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        client.close();
    }

}
```

This can be used as a source in your Processor as follows,

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class StreamProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<String> ampsStream = env
                .addSource(new AMPSSource("flink-consumer", "tcp://127.0.0.1:9007/amps/json", "test-topic"));

        ampsStream.print();
        env.execute();
    }
}
```

**Note: The RichSourceFunction implementations have a parallelism of 1.** To enable parallel execution, the user defined source should implement `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ParallelSourceFunction` or extend `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.RichParallelSourceFunction`

Comment: Actually when we are connecting to AMPS server its throwing error like                             com.crankuptheamps.client.exception.AuthenticationException: Logon failed for user "xyzabc"
 at com.crankuptheamps.client.Client.syncAckProcessing(Client.java:3898)
 at com.crankuptheamps.client.Client.syncAckProcessing(Client.java:3743)

Comment: Check out the official AMPS docs, you can find directions for authentication if your server is secured. [This page](http://devnull.crankuptheamps.com/documentation/html/5.2.3.1/dev-guides/java/html/chapters/first-program.html#providing-credentials-in-a-connection-string) provides a way to pass on `creds` in connection string.

Comment: Have added the authenticator API. After that its working fine..thanks

Comment: @Thirunavukkarasu Great! You may want to try extending `RichParallelSourceFunction` for better performance by increasing the source parallelism.

Comment: Sure. Let me try to explore that too